# Python Nslookup Not working

Tags: python, dns, ip, runtime-error, nslookup

I have a list about domains. I want to read this domains from a text file and then check nslookup. But my code is not working. Whats wrong in my code?

```
new_days = open("ip.txt","w")
with open("domains.txt", "r") as f:
  for date in f:
    dateb = str(date)
    dateb = dateb.replace("\n"," ")
    answers = dns.resolver.query(dateb, 'A')
    for rdate in answers:
      b = str(dateb) + str(rdate)
      new_days.write(b)
```

Comment: what do you get

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "domain.py", line 16, in <module>
    answers = dns.resolver.query(dateb, 'A')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1132, in query
    raise_on_no_answer, source_port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dns/resolver.py", line 1051, in query
    raise NXDOMAIN(qnames=qnames_to_try, responses=nxdomain_responses)
dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN: None of DNS query names exist: www.google.com\010.

Comment: there is a linefeed `\010` at the end.dateb=dateb.strip()

Answer (score 0):

You need to install dnspython module and import dnspython module in your python script in the first place. Also, it's advisory to also attach your error output.

```
#import dnspython module
import dns.resolver

new_days = open("ip.txt","w")
with open("domains.txt", "r") as f:
  for date in f:
    dateb = str(date)
    dateb = dateb.replace("\n"," ")
    answers = dns.resolver.query(dateb, 'A')
    for rdate in answers:
      b = str(dateb) + str(rdate)
      new_days.write(b)
```

Comment: I already import dns.resolver. Its about reading string from file. Cause i run same code with same way it worked:                                   
import dns.resolver

a = 'google.com'
answers = dns.resolver.query(a, 'A')
for rdata in answers:
    print rdata